# ctx.switchToHttp is not a function

Tags: nestjs

I'm using nestjs and I was trying to create a custom decorator:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from './user.entity';

export const GetUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data, ctx: ExecutionContext): User => {
    const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return req.user;
  },
);
```

The decorator is used here:

```
  @Post('/test')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  test(@GetUser() user: User) {
    console.log(user);
  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
[Nest] 15053   - 26/03/2020, 13:28:19   [ExceptionsHandler] ctx.switchToHttp is not a function +61625ms
TypeError: ctx.switchToHttp is not a function
    at /Users/nelson.larios/Documents/nestjs/nestjs-task-management/dist/auth/get-user.decorator.js:5:21
    at /Users/nelson.larios/Documents/nestjs/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:115:35
    at resolveParamValue (/Users/nelson.larios/Documents/nestjs/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:143:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at pipesFn (/Users/nelson.larios/Documents/nestjs/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:148:45)
    at /Users/nelson.larios/Documents/nestjs/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:36:36
    at InterceptorsConsumer.intercept (/Users/nelson.larios/Documents/nestjs/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/interceptors/interceptors-consumer.js:10:20)
    at /Users/nelson.larios/Documents/nestjs/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:45:60
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async /Users/nelson.larios/Documents/nestjs/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:8:17
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Nest are you on?

Comment: Hi, Jay. Version 7.0.2

Comment: `nest info` prints out 7.0.2? Only other time I've seen this error is when there was still some code from Nest v6 lying around. Do you have a repository which reproduces it?

Comment: Ok, Jay. That was really it. For some reason my nest version 7.0.2 created the package.json with version 6. Weird right? Thanks a bunch, man. If you hadn't mentioned that I would never had checked. Keep safe!

Comment: The question is, how did this happened? I had create another application before and this didn't happened.

Comment: Was this from an existing project, or a brand new one both times?

Answer (score 8):

Prior to version 7.x, Custom Decorators were static, and thus did not get the `ExecutionContext` passed to them.  In [v7.x release, this has been added](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/3070).

As mentioned in comments on the OP's question, you need to upgrade to this version to get the [example in the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) working.